# Print an integer to the screen from the Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to connect to a FTP-server. And I want a confirmation that I am connected.

This is my code:

```
package no.ftptesting.oversikt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class ftptestingActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FTPClient ftp;

    ftp = new FTPClient();
    try {
        int reply;
        ftp.connect("server",21);
        System.out.println("Connected.");

        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I want to print out a confirmation and the reply-integer on the screen. How can I do this?

Comment: Create a layout that includes a "status" `TextView` (or similar) and update it with the information you need?

Comment: How about Including TextView in your layout and displaying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make a `TextView` and print your output on this.

Heres the [Hello World example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html), which shows you exactly how to do this.

You could also print a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html), but thats only shown for a short while.

Comment: For anyone looking for the latest link to the hello world example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html